# How to edit a DataGridView with suggested values

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to have a `DataGridView`, in which I can edit the rows.

But **I want to have a list of suggested values displayed under the field, and I want to be able to select a value from this list** to complete the edited field.

Kind of the google search Field on the web, but in a table.

For me that sounded simple, but after searching how to do it, I found it's not as simple as I thought. Does somebody know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: WIll each field in each row have the same or different suggestions? Shall the user be able to ignore the suggestions? Is the DGV data bound?

Comment: You have to create you own DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: @TaW Every field would have a different suggestion. Yes, the user is able to ignore the sugestions. And yes, the DGV is data Bounded

Comment: _Every field would have a different suggestion_ Meaning each row? Where will the values come from and how are they linked to the row?

Comment: @TaW yes and no. Every "editable" field will have there own suggestions value list, but there is only one editable field per row. These values will come from a query to another table. These values will help to autocomplete the word the user is inputing in the field.